# No DLL access when created by IL Generator

Tags: .net, dll, reflection.emit, ilgenerator

I created a dummy DLL. I was expecting I can access `S1` in the namespace. I can see my function and I can see the struct with il dasm when its in exe form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics.SymbolStore;
using System.IO;

namespace emitTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName();
            assemblyName.Name = "HelloWorld";
            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
            ModuleBuilder module;
            module = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("HelloWorld.exe", true);
            TypeBuilder typeBuilder = module.DefineType("MyNamespace.HelloWorldType", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);
            MethodBuilder methodbuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Main", MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(string[]) });
            var s1 = module.DefineType("Space.S1", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Sealed |  TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.SequentialLayout | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit, typeof(System.ValueType));
            s1.DefineField("a", typeof(int), FieldAttributes.Public);
            s1.CreateType();
            ILGenerator ilGenerator = methodbuilder.GetILGenerator();
            ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            Type helloWorldType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
            if (false)
            {
                // set the entry point for the application and save it
                assemblyBuilder.SetEntryPoint(methodbuilder, PEFileKinds.ConsoleApplication);
                assemblyBuilder.Save("HelloWorld.exe");
            }
            else
            {
                assemblyBuilder.SetEntryPoint(methodbuilder, PEFileKinds.Dll);
                assemblyBuilder.Save("HelloWorld.dll");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what is the problem in more detail? What exactly does the code do? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I'm expecting I can reference `HelloWorld.dll` and be able to write `using Space; //its a namespace` and `S1 mystruct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what exactly are you asking, but I think the problem is that you're always defining the module as `HelloWorld.exe`. What you need to do is to make sure the module name matches the file name.

So, if you want to save the assembly as `HelloWorld.dll`, then you need to set the module name to `HelloWorld.dll` too.

Comment: Oh wow that was it I completely didn't notice 'exe' was defined in two places! Now i wonder WHY its defined there (`msdn DefineDynamicModule`)

Comment: I think it's because a module of an assembly can also be in a separate file (`.netmodule`).

Comment: Yeah this has tripped me up at least a 1000 times.